# url changes but not the component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

I want to redirect from saga middleware but the way I am doing just changes the url but shows the same page where I am currently. This is what I did.

```
function forwardTo(location) {
  console.log("location", history, location);
  history.push(location);
}

yield call(forwardTo, "/");
```

I am using redux toolkit and here is my setup

```
export function configureAppStore() {
  const reduxSagaMonitorOptions = {};
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware(reduxSagaMonitorOptions);
  const { run: runSaga } = sagaMiddleware;

  // // Create the store with saga middleware
  const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware];

  const enhancers = [
    createInjectorsEnhancer({
      createReducer,
      runSaga,
    }),
  ];

  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: createReducer(),
    middleware: [...getDefaultMiddleware(), ...middlewares],
    devTools:
      /* istanbul ignore next line */
      process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ||
      process.env.PUBLIC_URL.length > 0,
    enhancers,
  });

  // Make reducers hot reloadable, see http://mxs.is/googmo
  /* istanbul ignore next */
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept("./reducers", () => {
      forceReducerReload(store);
    });
  }

  return store;
}

app.js
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router>
     <RouterApp />
  </Router>
</Provider>
```

reducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

/**
 * Merges the main reducer with the router state and dynamically injected reducers
 */
export function createReducer(injectedReducers = {}) {
  // Initially we don't have any injectedReducers, so returning identity function to avoid the error
  if (Object.keys(injectedReducers).length === 0) {
    return (state) => state;
  } else {
    return combineReducers({
      ...injectedReducers,
    });
  }
}
```

utils/history.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
const history = createBrowserHistory();
export default history;
```

How can i redirect to a particular route from saga middleware?

The reason why I am not using connected-react-router is https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/deep-redux-integration

I am not quite sure so I want to understand the recommended way to dispatch router action from saga.

UPDATED CODE

```
export function createReducer(injectedReducers = {}) {
  // Initially we don't have any injectedReducers, so returning identity function to avoid the error
  const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    ...injectedReducers,
    router: connectRouter(history),
  });
  return rootReducer;
```

}

index.js

```
const ConnectedApp = ({ Component }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Component />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>
);

const render = (Component) => {
  ReactDOM.render(<ConnectedApp Component={Component} />, MOUNT_NODE);
};
```

I get following issue Uncaught Could not find router reducer in state tree, it must be mounted under "router"

Comment: We use [connected-react-router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router) to dispatch navigation actions to the redux store.

Comment: Can i directly import history on my reducer.js and create `createRootReducer(history)`?

Comment: No. If you read the steps for usage you create a function that takes a history object (`createRootReducer(history)`) and create a history object to be passed to the `connected-react-router` middleware.

Comment: How did you import `history` in the saga?

Comment: its through import { createBrowserHistory } from "history"; This might need in several places so I have this in utils.

Comment: @DrewReese it is giving me an error which i have updated in my code. Can you look at it, please?

Comment: Nothing is standing out as overtly incorrect in the two added snippets. I'm not sure if this would cause the error, but have you also added the router middleware? Otherwise we may just need to see a bit more of the setup.

Comment: I have added router middleware as well.

Comment: Can you please share code for `<RouterApp />`?